# Serialize an object to XML without using attributes

Tags: c#, xml

Is it possible to control `XmlSerializer`/`DataContractSerializer` behavior without specifying any serialization attributes?

To be more specific, I want to control the serialization (`XmlIgnore`, custom attribute name etc.), but without decorating my properties.
Use cases:

- A large existing class, which I don't wish to pollute with serialization attributes
- Serializing a class for which no source code is available
- Switching from using `XmlSerializer` to `DataContractSerializer` to JSON without changing class code

For example, how would I serialize the following without uncommenting the attributes:

```
// [Serializable]
public MyClass
{
    // [XmlIgnore] - The following property should not be serialized, without uncommenting this line
    public int DontSerializeMeEvenThoughImPublic { get; set; }

    // [XmlAttribute("another_name")] - should be serialized as 'another_name', not 'SerializeMeAsXmlAttribute'
    public double SerializeMeAsXmlAttribute { get; set; }

    // [DataMember] - should be included
    private string IWantToBeSerializedButDontDecorateMeWithDataMember { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to serialize without attributes?

Comment: You should be able to serialise fine without attributes, you just cannot control the output.

Comment: Should it obey the uncommented attributes in your sample? If not, please remove them.

Comment: @BenRobinson - that is untrue. For example, `DontSerializeMeEvenThoughImPublic` would be serialized even though it should be ignored

Comment: @bavaza, as I said "you cannot control the output".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't (do it elegantly).
The only way to modify the way the `XmlSerializer` serializes classes is by using attributes (by the way `SerializableAttribute` is not required). The `DataContractSerializer` is even worse.

One possible solution is to create intermediate classes for XML serialization/desrialization and use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) to copy the data between the "real" class and mediator.
I've used this approach to keep the front end XML serialization concerns outside of my business logic data types.

Comment: big big like for suggesting Automapper. A great library :-)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but for the XmlSerializer part, it's interesting that no one has suggested the use of Attribute overrides.

Although not solving the Private property, but AFAIK you can't do that with attributes either, so the only route there would be the IXmlSerializable interface.

But what you can do by adding Attributes should be possible with overrides as well.

The following should work for the change wishes reflected by the outcommented XmlAttributes:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        overrides.Add(typeof(MyClass), "DontSerializeMeEvenThoughImPublic", new XmlAttributes { XmlIgnore = true });
        overrides.Add(typeof(MyClass), "SerializeMeAsXmlAttribute", new XmlAttributes { XmlAttribute = new XmlAttributeAttribute("another_name") });
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass), overrides);
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, new MyClass());
            Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Serialization via `XmlSerializer` should work without the attributes.

Comment: How would you ignore the first property in the question without attributes?

Comment: I guess this would be impossible without the attributes. On the other hand, would it hurt? Your possibilities are a bit limited if you cannot change the class in question. It depends a bit on the overall goal.

Comment: I will not be able to control the serialization. For example, `DontSerializeMeEvenThoughImPublic` would be serialized even though it should be ignored.

Comment: One possibility would be to have an adapter class which has the same data members and can be assigned from/to the previously existing type. However, this approach is not very elegant and would tend to be hard to maintain.

Comment: @PatrickHofman You would use XmlAttributeOverrides, they won't solve the Private property though AFAIK...